# How To Prevent ClickOnce UI Project Also Opening Dotnet Console

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, console, clickonce

I got a project output with **dotnet mage** command block for click once. I installed this and when I run the program with the application manifest file, the dotnet console also opens. **When i close console application closing as well.**

[image: 1]

My program's output type is set to "WinExe" so it's not a console application.

Since the program is in .Net 6 and above, it has Launcher.exe.

**Launcher.manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Launcher" processorArchitecture="msil" version="7.0.0.0" />
  <file name="Launcher.exe" />
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" version="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" version="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Deployment" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" version="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Also there is my setup application manifests:
ProjectName.exe.Manifest:

```
<entryPoint>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Launcher" version="7.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
    <commandLine file="Launcher.exe" parameters="" />
  </entryPoint>
  <trustInfo>
    <security>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">        
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.